# Showing that the kernel of an evaluation map is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $f: R[x]\to R$ be a ring homomorphism defined by

$$ f(r_0 + r_1 x + \cdots + r_n x^n) = r_0 + r_1 + \cdots + r_n. $$

I need to prove that $\ker f$ is a principal ideal of $R[x]$, and find an element of $R[x]$ that generates $\ker f$.

Apparently, here $f$ is the evaluation map that evaluates every polynomial with coefficients in $R$ at $x = 1$. However, I can't even figure out what the kernel of this homomorphism is, let alone how to show that it is a principal ideal, since I can't figure out when $r_0 + r_1 + \cdots r_n = 0$.

My thoughts thus far are that if $n+1$ is even (i.e., when there is an even number of terms), the image of $f$ is $0$ when $\forall i$ from $i = 0$ to $n$, $\exists j$ from $j = 0$ to $n$ such that $i \neq j$ and $r_i = -r_j$.

On the other hand, if $n+1$ is odd, then $n$ must be even. So supposing that an odd number $k$ of the terms $= 0$, then for the remaining $m:=n+1 - k$ terms, of which there are an even number, if we renumber them as $s_0$ to $s_{m-1}$, then the image of $f$ is $0$ when $\forall i$ from $i = 0$ to $m-1$, $\exists j$ from $j = 0$ to $m-1$ such that $i \neq j$ and $s_i = -s_j$.

I don't, however, know how to write this compactly and in such a way where it would be easy to show that it is principal and to tell what element of $R[x]$ generates it.

Could somebody please assist me with this? **First**, if I am not on the right track with identifying the kernel of $f$, please help me do so. **Secondly**, once I have the kernel identified, how do I show that it is a principal ideal of $R[x]$ and (**thirdly**) go about identifying its generator?

Thank you ahead of time for your help and patience!

Comment: Since you've already identified that this is basically evaluation at the identity, one can see that the kernel should be the set of polynomials with root $1$. Hence I suppose that $\ker f = (X-1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly $x-1\in\ker f$. Therefore the ideal $I$ generated by $x-1$ is contained in $\ker f$.

Suppose $p(x)\in \ker f$; then
$$
p(x)=(x-1)q(x)+r
$$
for some $r\in R$ and some $q(x)\in R[x]$. Substituting $1$, we get
$$
0=p(1)=(1-1)q(x)+r
$$
and therefore $r=0$, so $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)\in I$.

Summing up, $I=\ker f$.

Comment: I suppose we are trying to show that $p(x) = x-1$ here? Anyway, if $p(x) \in \ker f$ and $f$ is the evaluation map where $x = 1$, I would need $p(1) = 0$, right? So, I would need $p(1) = (1-1)q(1) + r$, which implies that $r = 0$?

Comment: @ALannister Sure:you want to show $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)$, that is, $r=0$. Polynomial division (with remainder) is always possible when the divisor is monic.

Comment: So I want to show that $q(x) = 1$ as well?

Comment: @ALannister Why? You want to show $p(x)$ belongs to the ideal generated by $x-1$.

Comment: @ALannister Not at all: $p(1)=(1-1)q(1)+r=r$. The value of $q$ at $1$ is immaterial.

Comment: okay so $x-1 \in \ker f$, and up until now, I misunderstood the rest of what you were doing. I thought that we needed to show that $x-1$ WAS the $\ker f$. But we don't actually have to identify exactly what the $\ker f$ is equal to here in order to get the job done, do we? All we need to do, as you said is show that $\ker f \in (x-1)$, and to do that, we must show that any $p(x) \in \ker f $ belongs to $(x-1)$. Is the answer to the second part: "find an element of $R[x]$ which generates $\ker f$" $x-1$, then?

Comment: @ALannister No. You're on the wrong track. The ideal generated by $x-1$ consists of all polynomials of the form $(x-1)q(x)$, where $q$ is an arbitrary polynomial.

Comment: which we have shown, is in the kernel. But, once we have that every such polynomial $p(x) \in \ker f$ can be expressed as $p(x) = (x-1)q(x)$, how do we make the leap to conclude that the set of all $(x-1)q(x)$ is an ideal, that $\ker f$ is a principal ideal, and $x-1$ generates $\ker f$?

Comment: @ALannister I added the complete argument. The set of all $(x-1)q(x)$ is an ideal by general theory.

Comment: thanks! Believe it or not, continuing to write things out, I was able to get there: since $p(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial in $\ker f$, we conclude that every such polynomial can be expressed as $p(x) = (x-1)q(x)$, for some $q(x) \in R[x]$. Then, $\ker f \in$ the set of all multiples of $x-1$ in $R[x]$. So, coupled with the earlier thing we said about how all multiples of $x-1$ in $R[x]$ are contained in $\ker f$, we have that $\ker f = $ this set. Since $f$ is a ring homomorphism, $\ker f$ is an ideal, and an ideal consisting of all multiples of a single element is principal ideal.